# mac issue importing a cert signed by a dev issuer into the keychain

Tags: macos, ssl-certificate, keychain

I'm working on a development task where devices can register with a central command and control.  When they register the C&C with create and sign a cert for them.  This cert is also used to communicate with web services provided.  I need to switch between different groups of devices management by different C&C. However, When I try to import certs from the different groups so I can test out connections sometimes nothing appears to happen in the keychain access app.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because a cert reportedly from the same issuer has already been imported.  Each C&C uses the same common name so it thinks it already trust that C&Cs certs trusted.  However, these issuer's are different.  By deleting the other imported certs issued by the same common name I am able to import successfully.  I don't know if this is a bug or if its supposed to work this way.